# Is erasing flash memory supposed to be this slow? (S25FL127S)

Tags: spi, flash, non-volatile-memory, performance

I'm trying to interface with a Cypress/Infineon S25FL127S (https://www.cypress.com/file/177961/download - 16MB SPI Flash module) and the Erase commands are very slow.  Testing with two different boards a number times shows it takes an average of **2.5 seconds to erase a single block** (command 0xD8) or sector (command 0x20).

**Is this normal?**

Once a block is erased, the write takes about 15ms, much more what was I was expecting.  I couldn't find anything about this in the datasheet (above) and I've never used an SPI flash module before so I'm just trying to understand if there is something wrong or if this is par for the course and I should just ensure my software will function properly with these multi-second lags in cases where flash needs to be erased before writing.  (I imagine erases are normally done in batches ahead of time so the writes can happen quicker, but still, 2.5 seconds is painful.)

Comment: Section 9.10 on page 109 of the datasheet should set your expectations for erase timing. 64k top/bottom sectors typically take 2.1 seconds to erase, but can take as long as 12.6 seconds. 256k sectors typically take 0.52 seconds but can take as long as 3.12 seconds to erase.

Comment: _"2.5 seconds is painful."_ - you never worked with UV EPROMs then. 15-20 minutes under the UV eraser, then blank check and discover that it's _still_ not fully erased!